# Como criar um grupo de rotas no Blazor com parâmetros?

Tags: c#, blazor

Estou tentando criar uma estrutura no meu Blazor Client-Side assim:

- Pages

  - Users

    - Index.razor
    - Show.razor

Na minha página **Index** está assim no começo:

`@page "/users/"`

E na minha página **Show** está assim:

`@page "/users/{id}"`

Quando eu navego na rota `users` funciona normalmente. Mas quando tem parâmetro e está em outra página `.razor`, não funciona.

Não encontrei nada que me ajudasse.

E só pra constar, essa é a primeira pergunta oficial de uma dúvida sobre **Blazor** no PT StackOverflow.

Comment: Eu não sei o que eu fiz, talvez tenha reiniciado o server, não sei. Sei que nessa estrutura que postei acima está funcionando agora.

Comment: O que não tem solução, solucionado está.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente criar um parâmetro na página `Show.razor`

```
@page "/users/{id:int}"
@page "/users/{id}"

@code {
    [Parameter] public int? id { get; set; }
}
```

Certifique-se de que você está navegando para a página Show.razor passando o parâmetro "id" corretamente. Você pode fazer isso usando um link ou redirecionando programaticamente.
Por exemplo, você pode criar um link na página Index.razor para navegar para a página Show.razor com um parâmetro "id" assim:

```
<a href="/users/123">Ir para a página de usuário 123</a>
```

Agora, na `Show.razor`, você pode acessar o valor do parâmetro `"id"` da seguinte forma:

```
    @if (id.HasValue)
{
    <p>O valor do parâmetro "id" é: @id</p>
}
else
{
    <p>O parâmetro "id" não foi fornecido na rota.</p>
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Tente colocar sua rota no Program.cs, neste exemplo tem duas rotas

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=namedocontroller}/{action=metodo}/{id?}");

//endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
//name: "menu",
//pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

});

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).